# SQL Query with LEFT JOIN Issue

Tags: sql, left-join

I am having problems with a left join SQL query but can't see why it isn't working. I have 3 tables: customers, purchases and payments, and i'm trying to select customers who's total purchases cost is less than their total payments (i.e. they have a balance greater than 0).

So far, I have the following:

Tables:

```
Customers

id | Name


Purchases

id | customerid | cost


Payments

id | customerid | paymentamount
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT  a.*, 
COALESCE(b.totalCost , 0) as totalCost, 
COALESCE(c.totalPayments , 0) as totalPayments, 
COALESCE(b.totalCost , 0) - COALESCE(c.totalPayments , 0) AS Balance 
FROM customers a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  customerid, SUM(cost) AS totalCost FROM purchases GROUP BY customer) b ON a.id = b.customerid 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customerid, SUM(paymentamount) AS totalPayments FROM payments GROUP BY customerid) c ON a.id = c.customerid 
WHERE Balance > 0"
```

When I run the query, I get the error 'Unknown column 'Balance' in 'where clause'' even though I have defined Balance.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `BALANCE` is an ALIAS given on the expression. Use the expression on the `WHERE` clause instead of the `ALIAS`

```
WHERE   COALESCE(b.totalCost , 0) - COALESCE(c.totalPayments , 0) > 0
```

the other way is to wrap the whole statement with a subquery so you can use the alias on the `WHERE` clause of the outer query.

The reason why you cannot use `ALIAS` that is created on the same level of the `WHERE` clause is because `WHERE` clause executes first than the `SELECT` clause where the `ALIAS` is created.

Here's the SQL Order of Operation:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Comment: you're welcome. `:)` if you want to wrap the statement in a subquery see @a_horse_with_no_name 's answer  too `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't reference an alias on the same "level" where it's defined.

You need to wrap everything into a derived table:

```
select *
from (
   <your query goes here>
) t
where balance > 0
```